# How to extract the records which all are having date difference in below table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Based on below Picture i want to extract records where last enddate is not matching with next startdate . (e.g. 2nd row has end date 2030 and 1st has 2031)

Comment: Now that you have told us what you *want*, show us what you have *tried* and what errors you are getting. SO isn't a code writing service. Have some initiative. Providing you an answer with logic or functions you don't understand is just going to give birth to more questions. Also, [you shouldn't post screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and you **should** post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(startdate) over (partition by cardid, package order by startdate) as next_startdate
      from t
     ) t
where next_startdate <> enddate;
```